# Convert IntPtr to int* in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, intptr, managed-code

I have a C++ DLL returning an `int*` to a C# program.  The problem is the `int*` in C# remains `null` after the assignment.

When I assign the C++ result to an `IntPtr`, I get a correct non-null value.  However any attempt to convert this to an `int*` results in `null`.

I've tried:

```
IntPtr intp = cppFunction ();           // Non-null.

int* pi = (int *) intp;                 // Results in null.

int* pi = (int *) intp.ToPointer ();    // Results in null.


void* vp = intp.ToPointer ();

int* pi = (int *) vp;                   // Results in null, but vp is non-null.
```

How can I get a non-null `int*` ?

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: I used the standard malloc() function from msvcrt.dll as "cppFunction()". It worked okay for me, I could even read/write the allocated memory location.

When I assigned a random number to intp (IntPtr intp = (IntPtr)1000;), I got a NullPointerException only when dereferencing. Still, the pointer's value was never null...

Can you give me a small, complete program that produces the incorrect results?

Comment: do you have the option of refactoring the C++ so that you can pass in an IntPtr with the required memory allocated? it would be better that way - or hook up a callback to allocate the memory in C# as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378626/how-can-i-return-a-stringbuilder-or-other-string-buffer-from-a-pinvoke-native-ca

Answer (score 4):

You cppFunction declaration should be something like:

```
void cppFunction(ref int* ptr) {
   ptr = somevalue;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

You may find this useful also:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2902012.php

Comment: Thanks James.  I tried your method like this:

        [DllImport("vdrdll.dll", EntryPoint = @"?getLineContentsAsArg@@YAXAAPAH@Z")]
        public unsafe static extern void getLineContentsAsArg (ref int* lca);        


DLLEXPORT void getLineContentsAsArg (int*& lca)
{
 lca = calculateLineContents ();
}

A pointer value is assigned in the DLL, but when it gets back to C#, it's null.

I looked at your examples, and only the last one attempts to assign to a pointer variable in C#.  Every time I've tried this, the result of the assignement is null.

Can you see anything I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I will need to look at it more when I finish mowing, but, I realized that recently the way I solved this was that in C# I allocated a buffer, sent the pointer to the unmanaged code, along with an IntPtr to get the length.  The problem you are encountering is probably due to the fact you are expecting the C++ function to do the malloc and return the string. In that case you probably need to pass a pointer to the pointer, but I am not certain how you would free that in C# when you are done with it.

Comment: If you need the unmanaged code to do the malloc but you want it in the managed address space you could provide a callback of the form `void* callback(int length)` so the unmanaged code could ask the managed code to do the allocation. Newer C# version support unmanaged delegates and would be needed to define the callback. Another option is passing a buffer guaranteed to be large enough: `int cppFunction(ref int* ptr, void* buffer)` where the `int` return value is how many bytes were written to the `buffer`